# What is the best practice for handling an exposed seed phrase on NEAR Protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

When it's just an access key that is compromised on NEAR, it is easy to add a new key and delete the compromised one with `add-key` and `delete-key` commands.

But what if a 12-word seed phrase (eg for a wallet recovery) is compromised for an account like `foo.near`? How do you swap keys safely such that the account is no longer compromised (and you don't have to create a new account)?

Comment: One clunky path is to: 
1. use the seed phrase to recover a wallet into MyNearWallet
2. select to download the local private key under "account" tab (or login from CLI directly)
3. use that local private key to generate a public key and add that keypair as a full access one so you can develop locally
4. Generate a new keypair locally
5. Add this new public key as full access using the old keypair
6. Remove the old keypair

It still leaves potentially a substantial number of remaining public keys that were generated using the old private key (for old accounts with lots of activity).

Comment: Presumably you also need to understand, for heavily used accounts, which of the access keys on the account map to the compromised seed phrase so you can remove all of them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75085866/test-which-public-keys-were-generated-by-a-specific-private-key

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the account and transfer funds. Then you can create an account with the same name and the wallet will generate a new seed phrase

Comment: I just tested this using `near-cli`. I created an account, and cached the seed phrase. 

- Then I called `near delete $accountId $beneficiaryID` 
- Then I created the account _again_ and received a different seed phrase than before.

Is this best practice? I'm not entirely sure, but I can't think of another method specifically targeting the seed phrase.

Comment: For mature accounts, it would be strongly preferable not to have to delete the account, as many things linked to it (like social credit) would not be directly transferrable to a new account.  I updated the question to reflect this.