# Test which public keys were generated by a specific private key

Tags: nearprotocol

Let's say I've used `near keys foo.near` to identify all the keys for a given account and I want to understand which of those public keys were generated by a particular private key.  How would I do that most easily?

Comment: This could be useful for correcting an exposed seed phrase issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75084026/what-is-the-best-practice-for-handling-an-exposed-seed-phrase-on-near-protocol/75084629#75084629

Answer (score 0):

If you know the private key in question, this is a pretty trivial problem. You can use `near-api-js` to generate the KeyPair and get the public key. A quick code-snippet:

```js
const { KeyPair } = require("near-api-js");

let keyPair = KeyPair.fromString(secretKey);
let publicKey = keyPair.getPublicKey().toString();
```

At this point, you have the Public Key and can compare with the keys returned from the CLI.

Comment: But isn't `KeyPair.fromString` generating a random public key from the private key, so there's no such thing as "the" keypair or "the one" public key?  In that case, it wouldn't provide a useful comparison with the public keys in question (all or none of which may have been generated by the private key).

Comment: @ErikTrautman `KeyPair.fromString` will generate a KeyPair based on the secret key passed in. What you're thinking about is `KeyPair.fromRandom()`.